# Azure App service linux ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html2text'

Tags: linux, flask, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I am trying to run a python flask app on azure app service for linux and I am deploying it using git hub actions, but I am running in to ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html2text' Error. Below are app service logs :

[image]

I am new to app service and flask applications and dont understand what is the reason as the build of the application is fine and all dependencies from requirement.txt are installed.

Here are the logs of my build showing the package getting installed :

[image]

I need support here guys ! Thanks.

Comment: Please copy&paste logs instead of screenshots. This makes it possible for future people with the same problem to find your question.

Comment: Run the command `sudo pip install html2text` and check once

Comment: Is the issue resolved for you? I'm getting this error. If resolved then what did you do?

Answer (score 0):

- I have deployed Python Flask app in Azure using GitHub Actions.

Please Check the below Work around

[image]

- Make sure you are using the latest Python version

> No module named 'html2text'

- Create a python flask app in Local environment and push it to Git new repository.
- In Azure Portal => Deployment Center => Settings => Select GitHub as Source and provide the required details and Save.
  [image]

***Workflow in GitHubAction :***

[image]

- Verify,`html2text` must be installed in `dist-packages` folder.
- Issue will be resolved with the latest python version. If you are still getting the same error, Install the `html2text`.
- In `VSCode`, Terminal run the below command to install `html2text`

```cs
pip install html2text
```